# php date_diff function returns 0

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the difference between a date and current date but always returns 0.

```
$start_date = get_field('start_date', false, false); // 2021-12-15 09:00:00
$start_date = new DateTime($start_date);
$date_now = new DateTime();
if ($date_now > $start_date){
    $diff = date_diff($date_now, $start_date);  
}

echo $diff->format("%y Year %m Month %d Day %h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds");
```

Comment: it should work if your start date is valid, [demo](https://3v4l.org/VDWpl)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We'll be better able to assist you if you let us know what the value of `$start_date` currently is. You can use `die(get_field('start_date', false, false));` to print the current value to the page. Update your question to include the current value, I'm sure someone will be able to help you. Heck - once you see what the current value is, you may be able to answer the question yourself!

Comment: @btomw thanks for your suggestion but I wasn't able to solve it by myself :/ Both dates have the same format but $diff->format("%y Year %m Month %d Day %h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds") is echoing null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that `$date_now` is less than `$start_date`, so the code inside of the `if` block never runs. As such `$diff` is undefined. This should be throwing an error, which might have helped you suss this out - but sometimes error reporting is turned off. You might want to set up a local testing environment where error reporting is enabled, I'd bet you get to the bottom of this in no time. :-)

What you might be wanting is something closer to this:

```
$start_date = get_field('start_date', false, false); // 2021-12-15 09:00:00
$start_date = new DateTime($start_date);
$date_now = new DateTime();
$diff = date_diff($date_now, $start_date);  
$time_from_str = $diff->invert ? "ago" : "until"
echo $diff->format("%y Year %m Month %d Day %h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds") 
    . " " 
    . $time_from_str;
```

This always gets the interval of time, but adds some context for the end user to know if the time is in the past or the future.

Or, if you want to hard-stop at the start_date (which is implied by the id statement), you could do:

```
$start_date = get_field('start_date', false, false); // 2021-12-15 09:00:00
$start_date = new DateTime($start_date);
$date_now = new DateTime();
if($date_now > $start_date) {
    $diff = date_diff($date_now, $start_date);  
} else {
    $diff = new DateInterval("P0Y"); // an empty time interval, just so $diff is still defined
}

echo $diff->format("%y Year %m Month %d Day %h Hours %i Minute %s Seconds");
```

Hope that's helpful. Good luck!

Comment: I can't believe that was my error! thank you so much @btomw